# Error submission app update: packages Windows 8.1 (desktop and Phone bundle) + Windows 8.0

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-store

I try to send an update for my app to Windows Store by Windows Dev Center Dashboard, this update contains 3 packages: 2 for Windows 8.1 (Desktop and Phone) as a bundle and 1 for Windows 8.0 that does not support any bundle.

Before the new dashboard the package for Windows 8.0 was accepted too in this configuration... not now and it reports this error:

> A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows Phone 8.1 appxbundle. Subsequent submissions must continue to contain a Windows Phone 8.1 appxbundle.

but it isn’t a Phone package and for Windows 8.0 I can’t make a bundle! there is a solution? with the old dashboard that worked great.

Best regards,
Claudio

[image: New dashboard bundle error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it is applicable here. But in my case I've got the same error when updating UWP version of the application on the store where I had UWP, WP81 and W8.1 apps. The error was signaling the fact that the existent store UWP package was build with as a bundle but the new package was not.

So the solution was to replace in .csproj the `<AppxBundle>Never</AppxBundle>` with `<AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>`. If you publish from Visual studio directly you can do that from UI as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I deleted all the files in the folder where the package is building to the store. Then I created a package for store. This problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message appearing from nothing (just making a new build, no changes to platform). When I checked the box "do not automatically increment" (in UI, lead to `<AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>False</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>` in csproj) and filled in my own number, the package that came out was called:

```
 1.3.0.0_AnyCPU_bundle.appxupload
```

If I did not do it it looked like:

```
1.3.0.17_AnyCPU.appxupload
```

The latter did not work for some reason. So setting own build number fixed this particular problem for me. Why it fixed it? No clue.